# Cosmos DB error connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to call many times

Tags: arrays, node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-function-app

I have an array of items (to test I used around 250). Within each item is an ID that I am trying to call from CosmosDB. I am doing so in a simple for-loop

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; k++) {
    var func = find(context, arr[i].id)
}
```

Within `find` I simply call cosmosDB to read the file. This works fine on individual items, or if I use small arrays (20-50), however with large arrays I get the following error:

```
{ FetchError: request to mycosmossite/docs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 
  message:
   'request to mycosmossite/docs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  headers:
   { 'x-ms-throttle-retry-count': 0,
     'x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms': 0 } }
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I also get this when using `request-promise` from time to time but if I try again without changing anything it often works. I am not sure if this is linked

```
Exception: RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Can someone offer a solution so I can work on larger arrays here? Is this a throttling issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the Azure Cosmos DB JS SDK. Are you using the SDK to make these calls? We don't throw ETIMEDOUT anywhere inside the SDK so it is bubbling up from the NodeJS or Browser layer. Possibly you are overwhelming the networking stack or event loop by opening up many downstream connections and promises. As currently written, your code will open `arr.length` number of concurrent backend requests. Did you mean to `await` the result of each request? Example:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; k++) {
    var func = await find(context, arr[i].id)
}
```

You could also batch the requests using a package like [p-map](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-map) and using the concurrency parameter

Comment: I don't think I needed to `await` with `for` - I am using `@azure/cosmos` npm package if that clarifies the issue?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Without await the loop all the operations happen concurrently. But with await they will execute one at a time. In the OP it looks like you are not awaiting which causes all operations to execute concurrently. As the length of the array increases, you are overwhelming the network. This is a good blog post explaining await inside for loops https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/

Comment: Steve, an opt-in concurrency control might be a nice option, ey?

Comment: Bulk support is coming soon: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/7479. We do have concurrency control for cross partition queries. Did you have anything else in mind?